# High performance MySQL query to select highest ID from matching rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a higher performance query than what I'm using now.  I need to get the row with the highest `id` from a set of rows matching other criteria.  Right now I have something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE (thing = 'foo' OR thing = 'bar')
  AND used IS NULL
  AND stime = 0
  AND ~flags & 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

- `id` is the unique, sequential primary key.
- Other columns are non-unique but have indexes on them.

However, this query takes many seconds to run.  I need something close to sub-second performance, even .99 would be great.

Experimentally, I tried setting additional conditions in my `WHERE` clause on the `id` column, such as `max(id)` and `max(id) - 10000` .  For some values in place of the `10000` it works very fast, and that would suffice.  The problem is the distribution of the values in the other colums in the `WHERE` clause is highly irregular.  The last `10000` rows may or may not contain any rows matching the other conditions.  I need to always find at least one row, if possible.

Is there some small set of SQL statements (multiple fast queries would be fine, in other words) that can get me that last (highest `id`) matching row in a high-performance manner?

Comment: That is `~flags & 1` doing?  Stuffing values into bits is not a normal way to store data.

Comment: Selecting columns which don't have that bit set in the flags.  To misquote some guy, we go to work with the database we have, not the one we wish we had.  I have to live with those flags.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need performance, your best best is a second index on a virtual generated column:

```
alter table mytable add column my_conditions int generated always as
    (thing in ('foo', 'bar') AND used IS NULL AND stime = 0 AND (~flags & 1) );

create index idx_mytable_my_conditions on (my_conditions, id desc)
```

Then you can query the table as:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE my_conditions = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

And it should use the index for both filtering and the ordering.

Comment: That's radical. ;-)  I'll give it a try and see what happens.  Since I'll only be adding rows to this table once a day during a cron run, this might be a good solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that's scary fast.  Went from circa 9 seconds to circa .01 seconds in my development Docker container.  There's no free lunch, right?  What are the downsides of using this?

Comment: @CXJ . . . Indexes incur some overhead when data is modified (`insert`, `update`, `delete`).  Also, this index is very specific to your query so it is not general.  But if this is a common query, then it would seem to do what you want.    99.89% improvement is pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few changes you can do to improve the performance of the query. The first one I would try is to remove the `OR` operator and add an index.

#### Remove the OR Operator

Rephrase your query using `UNION`. For example:

```
select * from (
  select *
  from mytable 
  where thing = 'foo' and used is null and stime = 0 and ~flags & 1
  order by id desc
  limit 1
) z
union all
select * from (
  select *
  from mytable
  where thing = 'bar' and used is null and stime = 0 and ~flags & 1
  order by id desc
  limit 1
) y 
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

#### Add the index

The following index can help the optimizer:

```
create index ix1 on mytable (thing, stime, used, flags, id);
```

There are further optimizations that can be applied, but you can start trying with this.

Answer (score 1):

A better index would help, but cannot get completely past the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
INDEX(stime, used, thing, flags)
```

"have indexes on them" -- I assume you mean an individual index for each column.  When you have `AND`, it may be better to have a "composite" index.  Start with the `=` tests (note: `IS NULL` counts as `=`, then do the `IN` (which that `OR` turns into).

More on creating indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Actually, there are composite and individuals indexes.  Thanks for the advice on optimizing the order of the conditions, and the link!